# msbuild.exe does not run on Linux VM in Azure

Tags: linux, azure, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use Jenkins to run my unittests. I have made a Jenkins Project for a build with a buildstep "Build a Visual Studio Project using MSBuild". My Jenkins server is installed on a linux vm which is in Azure.

You can see it here in the Jenkins UI:

[image: Jenkins build step]

When I run the build I get this Console Output:

```
Path To MSBuild.exe: msbuild.exe
FATAL: Unable to use this plugin on this kind of operation system
Executing the command msbuild.exe /ContinuousIntegration/ContinuousIntegration.sln from 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CSHARP_CI_TEST - UNITTEST
[CSHARP_CI_TEST - UNITTEST] $ msbuild.exe 
/ContinuousIntegration/ContinuousIntegration.sln
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' changed 
build result to FAILURE 
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked 
build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I think the problem here is that I am trying to use msbuild.exe on a Linux VM. Is there a workaround for this or is it not possible to do this?

I have tried to use the msbuild.exe on the vm via a linux terminal, but it is not possible to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish your requirement you have to install '.NET Core SDK' in the Azure Jenkins Linux VM and then you may simply use 'Execute shell' build step with the command 'dotnet build ContinuousIntegration/ContinuousIntegration.sln'

To install '.NET Core SDK' in your Azure Jenkins Linux VM, please go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install and click on 'Linux' in that page and then select the required Linux distribution and follow the steps provided.

For more information on MSBuild support on various operating systems, please refer https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging-on-.Net-Core-MSBuild.md

Just FYI, I have tested and reproduced your scenario and faced the same error which you have mentioned and then I have followed the above process and resolved the issue successfully. So I hope this helps. Cheers!!

PS: in your shell script you have to cd to the right folder for this to work.

Comment: This helped me a bit, but the error I now get is:

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: /ContinuousIntegration/ContinuousIntegration.sln
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Corrected the path of sln file in my above answer from "/ContinuousIntegration/ContinuousIntegration.sln" to "ContinuousIntegration/ContinuousIntegration.sln". Note that i am considering sln file is under a directory named ContinuousIntegration which is under your Jenkins job's workspace. Change the complete path accordingly if your sln file is in different path.

Comment: It works but in your shell script you have to cd to the right folder for this to work. I have changed this in your answer as a PS

Comment: Approved the edit. And am glad that it worked for you. :)